# graphical models: integration rules over conditional prob distns

Tags: conditional-probability, graphical-model, conditional-independence

Suppose we have a graphical model over three RVs $a,b,c$ 
[image]
whose conditional independence structure gives 
$$
p(a,b,c) = p(a)\,p(c|a)\,p(b|c), \quad p(a,b)= \sum_c p(a,b,c) = p(a) \sum_c p(c|a)\, p(b|c).
$$
From [this](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/%7Ehic/CS7616/pdf/lecture6.pdf), how can I see that

$$\sum_c p(c|a)\, p(b|c) = p(b|a) ?$$
I tried
\begin{align}
\sum_c p(c|a)\, p(b|c) = \sum_c \frac{p(a|c)\, p(c)}{p(a)} p(b|c)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sum_c p(c|a)\, p(b|c) = \sum_c p(c|a)\, \frac{p(c|b)\, p(b)}{p(c)}
\end{align}
but still don't see it.

Is it the case that *any* time we have a sum over a RV's values (i.e., when summing over $c$ for arbitrary RVs $x,y$, we need to keep conditionals of the form $p(x|c)$ and $p(c|y)$ inside the summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' rule is unnecessary; it is simpler than that. Hint: use conditional independence. Or in other words, use:
$$
p(b \mid c) = p(b \mid c, a).
$$
What happens when you multiply both sides by $p(c \mid a)$?

Comment: I feel it should be $p(c|a)p(b|c,a)=p(b,c|a)$ (so that summing over $c$ gets rid of the $c$, but im not clear on why it is equal

Comment: @dunno that's it. you're done

Comment: thanks! can you provide some intuition/explanation to help me see why this is (outside of my trying to back into the solution)?

Comment: You can use CI then Bayes:
$$
p(c|a) p(b|c) \overset{CI}{=} p(c|a) p(b|c,a) = \frac{p(a,c)}{p(a)} \frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(a,c)} = p(b,c|a)
$$
so that when you marginalize, you get what you want.

Comment: @rrrrr I wouldn’t call that Bayes’

Comment: Ok ya, it's just definition I guess.